# Faster autocomplete/instant search for java mobile application

Tags: java, search, autocomplete, instant

I have implemented an autocomplete / instant search on a mobile application that I am developing using java (for the BlackBerry). The search is currently working, however I am looking for some tips on how I may be able to make the search faster.

Currently, every time that a letter is typed in the search bar, a search is executed on the current search string and the results are returned via a RESTful web service and displayed in the application.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how and when to execute the search to make it faster? I want to make the search as fast as possible, especially on a mobile platform where the service may not be the best in some areas (causing a slower search time).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently working on a similar problem, implementing an autocomplete for a mobile app.

If I'm understanding you correctly, whenever a letter is typed you perform a search through a RESTful interface, and return the results to the mobile app.

If this is correct, one suggestion I have is to not perform the search unless you have a minimum of two or three letters present, thus narrowing your search results, and hopefully speeding up the process.

Hope this helps.